# Need to copy a the contents of a very large table in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a database that stores billions of rows a day.   It is a 11G oracle database with RAC enable for same site HA and active dataguard for cross site.   We had to change the block size from 16k to 8k.  As this is not an online change we had to rename the table with months of data and create a new table.  Now we need to get the data from the original table into the new one.

Direct path inserts will lock the table, and regular inserts are causing lots of RAC waits.   Wonder if anyone has any best practices to move a ton of data from one table to another without stopping other processes from writing data to the new table (rapidly)

Comment: Have you licensed the the Partitioning option?  With tables that huge you really ought to.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_redefi.htm#CBBHFJAI).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name
TABLESPACE table_space_name
NOLOGGING
PARALLEL 4
AS SELECT * FROM existing_table_name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table <new table name> as <existing table name>;   
// its create a clone table with data.


create table <new table name> as <existing table name> 
where 1==2 <any false condition>;                        
// its create a clone table without data.
```